# Embed player with protected videos

Tags: youtube-api, video-streaming, jwplayer, vimeo-api, dailymotion-api

I'm looking for one solution to host videos with password protect and same time embed it in my website without need authentication.. so.. I'm imagine a solution like a player API with oauth api or other token/password solution to embed one protected video. I'm looking into vimeo, dailymotion, panda, mega, dropbox, youtube, streamnation... Anyone knows about one private streamming solution like that?

In case have no solution for it I will need use the jwplayer and one cloud or self storage solution...

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're lucky, Dailymotion recently added the password protection feature for videos :) You can set a password for a video, so the users will need this password to watch it.

If you're using the website interface, it's available in the upload panel general settings.

Using the API, you have to use the `password` field of the video object: https://developer.dailymotion.com/api#video-password-field